# Search input onchange causes crashing - how to make it a button to submit search

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor

I have an app in MeteorJS, which makes use of React (I am ok with JavaScript, but am on a learning curve starting with React). The current search input makes use of the onchange function of the input box BUT this is actually not desired as this slows the app considerably - making requests every time the user types.

I basically want the input to be basic input and then have a button to trigger the search.

Inline code, for calling the searchinput where needed;

```
<div className="col-md-4 col-xs-12" style={disabledStyling.control}>
    <SearchInput placeholder="Search" onChange={this.filterGames} value={filter} />
</div>
```

searchinput component;

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import Icon from '../Icon';
import Styles from './styles';

const SearchInput = ({ placeholder, value, onChange }) => (
  <Styles.SearchInput className="SearchInput">
    <Icon iconStyle="solid" icon="search" />
    <input
      type="text"
      name="search"
      className="form-control"
      placeholder={placeholder}
      value={value}
      onChange={onChange}
    />
  </Styles.SearchInput>
);

SearchInput.defaultProps = {
  placeholder: 'Search...',
  value: '',
};

SearchInput.propTypes = {
  placeholder: PropTypes.string,
  value: PropTypes.string,
  onChange: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};

export default SearchInput;
```

Hoping you all could help ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically what you need to do is use a `state` to store the value from the `onChange` event and later, on button click/form submit action you pass this value to the function that will actually fetch data.

[Here is a small example on code sandbox where you can see this being applied both on a functional component and on a class component](https://codesandbox.io/s/youthful-worker-2ifs1?file=/src/App.js)

lets assume your "wrapper" component is something like this:

```
const Form = () => {

 const filterGames = (event) => {
  // handle event and calls API
 }

 return (
  <div className="col-md-4 col-xs-12" style={disabledStyling.control}>
   <SearchInput placeholder="Search" onChange={filterGames} value={filter} />
  </div>
 )
}
```

What we need to do here, is basically adding the state and handle it without calling the API and a button to actually call the API.

```
const Form = () => {

 const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState('');

 const filterGames = (event) => {
  // handle event and calls API
 }

 // this will store the value locally on the state
 const handleInputOnChange = (event) => {
  setInputValue(event.target.value);
 }

 return (
  <div className="col-md-4 col-xs-12" style={disabledStyling.control}>
   <SearchInput placeholder="Search" onChange={handleInputOnChange} value={inputValue} />
   <button type='submit' onClick={filterGames}>Submit</button>
  </div>
 )
}
```

ps: you can also wrap the input + button with a `form` and use `form.onSubmit` instead of `button.onClick`.